# Hasse invariant of abelian varieties with complex multiplication

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, complex-multiplication

Is there a good way to compute Hasse invariants of elliptic curves or higher dimensional Abelian varieties with complex multiplication?

For example, if $E$ is an elliptic curve with CM by an imaginary quadratic field $K$, what are the possibilities for the valuation of the Hasse invariant of $E$ at $p$ depending on if $p$ splits/is inert/ramifies in $K/\mathbb{Q}$? What if $A$ is an Abelian variety of dimension $d$ with CM by a CM field $K$ with $[K:\mathbb{Q}] = 2d$, depending on what $p$ does in $K/K^+$ and in $K^+/\mathbb{Q}$?